# Chosen-select: Trying to press enter once to select option, press second time to activate button click without using form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I have an AngularJS application which is using the jQuery Chosen plugin. I have a dropdown list to let the user select a country, and a button that executes an angular function which pulls the currently selected value from the select dropdown and redirects the user to a page for that country.

My issue concerns the behavior of pressing *[enter]* when highlighting an option from the selectable elements. Using the code below, pressing *[enter]* while an option is highlighted will immediately execute the `goToCountry()` function without closing the selection dropdown first. I would like the first *[enter]* to close the select dropdown, setting the currently highlighted value as the selected option. Then a second *[enter]* should click the button next to the select element.

I am testing this to work with Chrome.

I am aware of the way to do this [using a form](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/434#issuecomment-20175841), but I would like to do this without using a form. Is this possible?

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.goToCountry = function() {
    $('#countryPicker option:selected').each(function(){
        //goes to detail page for $(this).val());
    });                
};

for (var i=0;i<countries.length;i++) {
    $('#countryPicker').append('<option value="' + countries[i].name + '">' + countries[i].name + '</option>');
}
$('#countryChooser').chosen();

$("#countryPicker_chosen").bind('keyup',function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13) {
        $("#goToCountryButton").click();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="countryPicker" data-placeholder="Pick a Country" class="chosen-select">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>

<button id="goToCountryButton" ng-click="goToCountry()">View</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue before where on click of any other control in page, the select options are not hidden (mainly in IE8). The problem was in the event propagation.

The workaround I did was to manually trigger a document click event on a safe point in the page to hide the select option.